# Automated alternative for initiating a rolling update for a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

So in order to update the images running on a pod, I have to modify the deployment config (yaml file), and run something like `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`.

This means, if I'm not editing the yaml file manually I'll have to use some template / search and replace functionality. Which isn't really ideal.

Are there any better approaches?

It seems there is a `kubectl rolling-update` command, but I'm not sure if this works for 'deployments'.

For example running the following: `kubectl rolling-update wordpress --image=eu.gcr.io/abcxyz/wordpress:deploy-1502443760`

Produces an error of:

```
error: couldn't find a replication controller with source id == default/wordpress
```

Comment: we need to replace the image version in the deployment for the upgrade. Helm will be helpful tool for development. take a look at https://helm.sh/ see it will fit for your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using this for changing images in Deployments:

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1
```

If you view the yaml files as source of truth then use a tag like `stable` in the yaml and only issue `kubectl set image` commands when the tag is moved (use the sha256 image id to actually trigger a rollout; the image names are matched like a string so updating from `:stable` to `:stable` is a noop even if the tag now points to a different image).

See [updating a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) for more details.

The above requires the deployment replica count to be set more then 1, which is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649024/1663462.

Comment: This does not do a rolling deployment though - unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: It does. Effectively this is `patch` for the Deployment.

Comment: When using `set image` I see this afterwards: 
`NAME                         READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE`
`wordpress-4023966612-99p4b   0/3       Pending       0          2s`
`wordpress-46128486-vl6f6     0/3       Terminating   0          1m`


The existing pods are terminating while the new pod hasn't stabilized.  That does not seem like a rolling update?

Comment: It works absolutely fine. Set `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` and `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` to your desired values (see the [api reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#rollingupdatedeployment-v1beta1-apps) and the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment) for details)