# Kubernetes deployment does not perform a rolling update when using a single replica

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I modified the deployment config (production.yaml), changing the container image value.

I then ran this: `kubectl replace -f production.yaml`.

---

While this occurred, my service did not appear to be responding, in addition:

`kubectl get pods`:

`wordpress-2105335096-dkrvg   3/3       Running   0          47s`

a while later... :

`wordpress-2992233824-l4287   3/3       Running   0          14s`

a while later... :

`wordpress-2992233824-l4287   0/3       ContainerCreating   0          7s`

It seems it has terminated the previous pod before the new pod is `Running`... Why?

---

**produciton.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
        - image: eu.gcr.io/abcxyz/wordpress:deploy-1502463532
          name: wordpress
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          env:
            - name: WORDPRESS_HOST
              value: localhost
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: username
          volumeMounts:
            - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html
        - image: eu.gcr.io/abcxyz/nginx:deploy-1502463532
          name: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: nginx
          volumeMounts:
            - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html
        - image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.09
          name: cloudsql-proxy
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
                    "-instances=abcxyz:europe-west1:wordpressdb2=tcp:3306",
                    "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
            - name: ssl-certs
              mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
            - name: cloudsql
              mountPath: /cloudsql
      volumes:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: wordpress-disk
            fsType: ext4

        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
        - name: ssl-certs
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/ssl/certs
        - name: cloudsql
          emptyDir:
```

Comment: Generally speaking, `kubectl describe rs FOO` will show the events related to that ReplicaSet, which sometimes(!) includes why Pods were killed. If it doesn't, then `kubectl get events` likely will -- provided that `get events` is run quick enough, as it has not been my experience that `get events` keeps a deep history of the events. So next time it happens, having that output can help us troubleshoot the situation

Comment: Also, (again, generally speaking) it is highly unwise to have a single Pod setup unless there is an amazing reason why having at least two will not work for the application in question. If for no other reason than what you just described becomes less of a big deal if _a_ Pod gets killed when that doesn't include 100% of your Pods

Comment: The single pod is really just for development purposes for now, so will set this to a reasonable value eventually. Thanks for the info.

Unfortunately I don't see anything significant within output of `kubectl describe rs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is correct according to the Kubernetes documentation. Assuming you specify `n` replicas for a deployment, the following steps will be taken by Kubernetes when updating a deployment:

1. Terminate old pods, while ensuring that at least `n - 1` total pods are up
2. Create new pods until a maximum of `n + 1` total pods are up
3. As soon as new pods are up, go back to step 1 until `n` new pods are up

In your case `n = 1`, which means that in the first step, all old pods will be terminated.

See [Updating a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) for more information:

> Deployment can ensure that only a certain number of Pods may be down while they are being updated. By default, it ensures that at least 1 less than the desired number of Pods are up (1 max unavailable).
>   Deployment can also ensure that only a certain number of Pods may be created above the desired number of Pods. By default, it ensures that at most 1 more than the desired number of Pods are up (1 max surge).
>   In a future version of Kubernetes, the defaults will change from 1-1 to 25%-25%.