# Does Kubernetes need a minimum number of replicas in order to carry out a rolling deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

Nearly 3 years ago, Kubernetes would **not** carry out a rolling deployment if you had a single replica ([Kubernetes deployment does not perform a rolling update when using a single replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638480/kubernetes-deployment-does-not-perform-a-rolling-update-when-using-a-single-repl)).

Is this still the case? Is there any additional configuration required for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to have a minimum number of replicas to rollout an update using Kubernetes Rolling Update anymore.

I tested it on my lab (v1.17.4) and it worked like a charm having only one replica.

You can test it yourself using this Katakoda Lab: [Interactive Tutorial - Updating Your App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-interactive/)

This lab is setup to create a deployment with 3 replicas. Before starting the lab, edit the deployment and change the number of replicas to one and follow the lab steps.

I created a lab using different example similar to your previous scenario. Here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container 
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Deployment is running with one replica only:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-6c4699c59c-w8clt   1/1     Running   0          5s
```

Here I edited my nginx-deployment.yaml  and changed the version of nginx to `nginx:latest` and rolled out my deployment running replace:

```
$ kubectl replace -f nginx-deployment.yaml 
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment replaced
```

Another option is to change the nginx version using the `kubectl set image` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment):

```
kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx-container=nginx:latest --record
```

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-566d9f6dfc-hmlf2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          3s
nginx-deployment-6c4699c59c-w8clt   1/1     Running             0          48s

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-566d9f6dfc-hmlf2   1/1     Running       0          6s
nginx-deployment-6c4699c59c-w8clt   0/1     Terminating   0          51s

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-566d9f6dfc-hmlf2   1/1     Running   0          13s
```

As you can see, everything worked normally with only one replica.

In the latest version of the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) we can read:

> Deployment ensures that only a certain number of Pods are down while
>   they are being updated. By default, it ensures that at least 75% of
>   the desired number of Pods are up (25% max unavailable).
>
> Deployment also ensures that only a certain number of Pods are created
>   above the desired number of Pods. By default, it ensures that at most
>   125% of the desired number of Pods are up (25% max surge).